# Websphere JMS Queue sending duplicate messages

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I am moving an application from Websphere 6.1 to 8.5. This application uses WAS MQ Queues configured at `Resources-> JMS-> JMS Providers` to send messages. However we noticed that upon moving to Websphere 8.5, the MQ Queues in 8.5 are sending duplicate messages approximately 10 for every 60 messages. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

In 6.1 we only had one server, In 8.5 we have two servers for the cluster.  When we Stopped one of them the duplicates reduced but haven't completely gone away.

Any ideas?